# In App Purchase Sandbox Orientation issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

My first screen of the app is in Landscape mode and rest of the screens are in portrait mode. when I do In-App-Purchase, some times I got the sandbox alert in landscape. I want it in Portrait mode only.

So Please let me know if you have any idea. Like why it is coming in landscape?